# RestKit fetch nested resources independently of the parent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to figure out how I can fetch a list of resources that are a child of another resource, but I want to request them independently of the parent resource. I have 2 classes: `User` and `Notification`. When I request a user object, it does not return a list of notifications, but at a later point I would like to fetch these notifications. For this, I want to use the URL

```
/users/:user_id/notifications
```

I've setup a route defined as

```
RKRoute *notificationsAll = [RKRoute routeWithClass:[Notification class] pathPattern:@"users/:userID/notifications" method:RKRequestMethodAny];
```

But how can I request this successfully. Obviously the router needs to be aware of the userID but I'm not sure how I can supply this. Previously I have set a transient property within an object, but in this case, I don't have an object to set a transient property so that doesn't work.

I assume I'm doing something completely wrong but any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your router to work you need to make a request using a `Notification` instance and the `Notification` class needs to have a property called `userID` that the route can extract to inject into the path pattern.

If `Notification` doesn't fit this role then you need to change the class associated with the route to one that does. That could be a dictionary or a custom object.

Comment: Can I do that though if I'm trying to request a collection of `Notification` objects rather than just the one?

Comment: Generally, yes. There aren't many cases where RestKit requires the 'requested' object to be the same as the response objects (this is generally why the response mappings state the class they apply to).

Comment: so which method would I use then? As I can't use `getObjectAtPath...` as that'll only return a single object but other methods don't allow passing a notification object?

Comment: Yes, `getObject:path:parameters:success:failure:`. It will 'return' a list of objects if that is what the response contains. The singular 'object' refers only to the object being used to make the request.

Comment: ok that's more or less working, although I'm now getting a duplicate notification appearing? What's the general way of creating my new notification object to request from, without having that object persist when the response is returned and the managed object context saved?

Comment: You can call `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` with a nil context and then just don't ever try to save the temporary managed object instance.

Comment: That's giving me the error `Failed to retrieve existing object with ID`. I'm using `NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Notification" inManagedObjectContext:[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext]];
        Notification *n = [[Notification alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];`

Comment: Hmmm, checking the code, not sure when it changed as I'm sure this did used to work, but RestKit now tries to save the request object so it can find it again later (even if it isn't required). This could be changed, but currently it means that you can't use a `Notification` object, you would need some class which isn't a type of managed object.

Comment: :( Is there no other way of fetching a list in this way without then creating a non `NSManagedObject` version of Notification?

Comment: You don't need to use a route. You can create the path explicitly using a format string...

Comment: Ah was hoping to avoid that and try and keep it tidy. Guess I'll have to do that then :(